# Best way to transfer folder from one PC to another with powershell? (SSH?)

Tags: powershell, ssh

To start off, I'll tell you everything if gathered over the last couple of weeks of research.
What I am attempting to do is;
Run an .exe file on a remote device, (which runs scans and saves their results as .txt files in D:\Scan Results.) Once completed, I would like these results, (D:\Scan Results) to be sent to myself.

I would like to be able to do this through the use of PowerShell. I have looked into SSH and port communication, but struggled with opening port 22.

Is SSH the way to go? I am not able to install any other remote desk software or anything, so that is out of the question.

Any replies and feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you simply use `Copy-Item -Path '\\RemotePC\D$\Scan Results\*.txt' -Destination 'X:\YourComputer\SomeFolder'`?
Copy-Item also has a `-Credential` parameter in case you need to access the files using some admin account

Comment: I am not connected to this remote device though. I'm guessing the "Copy-Item -Path..." would work when connected to the PC with, (let's assume remote user has sufficient SSH client software installed and port 22 open, and has an IP address = 10.0.0.10, for example). How would I setup this connection on the client side if this is the way to go, can it be done with a simple script? Thanks a lot for your reply Theo! I hope what I'm saying makes sense, I am new to PowerShell and SSH

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who cares or is interested;
The better way around this is to use Nmap's 'Ncat'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).